# Ломаются символы когда в видео добавляю субтитры

Tags: windows, windows-10, unicode

Есть видео и  у него есть субтитры. делаю перевод видео субтитров на русский и открываю файл через нотепад вроде всё ок вс на русском а в видео вместо субтитров на русском какието иероглифы .Windows 10

Comment: Пробуйте сохранять в разных кодировках файл субтитров.

Comment: Какой софт используется для просмотра видео с субтитрами? Или же смотрите на ТВ/приставке?